# Protractor E2E testing on Angular2: Page not loaded ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli, angular2-testing

I have been stuck for 2 days trying to create E2E tests for our angular2 application.
We used angular-cli to scaffold our whole app: our app is served correctly with ng serve or ng build. Therefore, we are able to deploy it successfully on a remote server.

However,  nothing seems to work when trying to test it with protractor. Once I run the command "protractor", chrome is launched and I directly get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. The page is not loaded and I get the following error in the console:
E/protractor - could not find Angular on page http://localhost:8100/ : retries looking for angular exceeded

System version:
Protractor: Version 4.0.11
Angular2: Version 2.1.0

protractor.conf.js

```
/ Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js

/*global jasmine */
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter')

exports.config = {
allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
],
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
},
directConnect: true,
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100',
framework: 'jasmine',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
},

onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
},
useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
        project: 'e2e'
    })
},
onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter())
}
}
```

e2e/app.po.ts

```
 import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor'

 export class KYCFRONTENDPage {
    navigateTo() {
            return browser.get('/')
        }

   getParagraphText() {
        return element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText()
        }
    }
```

e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts

```
 import { KYCFRONTENDPage } from './app.po';

 describe('kyc-frontend App', function() {
 let page: KYCFRONTENDPage;

   beforeEach(() => {
     page = new KYCFRONTENDPage();
   });

   it('should display message saying app works', () => {
      page.navigateTo();
       expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('app works!');
    });
   });
```

Comment: Can you check in which tag the 'ng-app' directive placed in login.html or index.html page?

Comment: Please find index.html below:



<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>KYCFRONTEND</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>

Comment: in which tag you could see the ng-app directive(either <html> or <body>)?

Comment: I ve put index.html above (previous comment),, there is no ng-app directive

Comment: add rootElement : 'body' in conf.js file and try to execute

Comment: unfortunately,it doesn t change anything. The application doesn't load. I get a blank chrome page mentioning : This site can't be reached ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED